# Quill - pasting custom embed sometimes return boolean instead of actual value

Tags: javascript, quill

I am using the Quill.js editor, and I have created a custom Embed like below:

```js
var Embed = Quill.import('blots/embed');
class QuillHashtag extends Embed {
    static create(value) {
        console.log(value);
        let node = super.create(value);
        node.innerHTML = value;
        return node;
    }
}

QuillHashtag.blotName = 'hashtag';
QuillHashtag.className = 'quill-hashtag';
QuillHashtag.tagName = 'span';

Quill.register({
    'formats/hashtag': QuillHashtag
});

var quill = new Quill('#templateEditor', {
    debug: 'debug',
    modules: {
        toolbar: {
            container: '#toolbar'
        }
    },
    placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
    readOnly: false,
    theme: 'snow'
});
```

I then simply have a button, that can insert this custom embed `QuillHashtag`:

```js
function insertVariable() {
   quill.focus();
   var selection = this.quill.getSelection();
   quill.insertEmbed(selection.index, 'hashtag', '#games');
   quill.setSelection(selection.index + selection.length + 1); //Place cursor to the right.
}
```

This works fine and the embedded hashtag is inserted to the editor. I

Something weird is happening though when I copy the hashtag and pasting it into the editor again **and** a space is present after the hashtag. When I do this, it will show `true` instead of the actual hashtag.

The thing is, it only shows the `true` value when there is a space after the hashtag.

## I have created a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xea8rs2h/2/).

See below small gif showing this behavior:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by adding the below to the `QuillHashtag` class:

```js
static value(domNode) {
    return domNode;
}
```

Comment: I come into the same problem and this answer is proven to be effective;